# Can I install a desktop without any other applications?

Tags: unity

I would like to know how I can install Ubuntu 11.10 + Unity without any other application production like Libre Office, FireFox and so on... Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a customized LiveCD. Try [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://uck.sourceforge.net/):

- Create bootable LiveCD with predefined languages based on original Ubuntu/Kubuntu live CD using wizard with GUI
- Build live CD with special features using scripts. It is possible to customize root filesystem (for example install/remove packages), ISO contents (add/remove docs, change names) and initrd (add modules to boot, change boot sequence)

Another solution seems to be [Reconstructor](https://code.lumentica.com/projects/reconstructor/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Try [ubuntu minimal iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)
it may the smallest possible desktop
you can add essential packages into it via [uck](http://uck.sourceforge.net/)